# how can i copy and paste only the unique values in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to copy and paste unique values of a column in vba. the challenges are the: the excel doesn't have a fixed position, the position can change based on the data. As can be seen in the picture, i want to take the unique values of the amount(abs)  of Columns A and paste then besides it on columns B, i don't want to touch the amounts in column A. there are a couple of empty cells between amount and absolute amount. both amount and absolute amounts are dynamic.

[enter image [[image: description]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei3oB.png) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T3Dl.png)

As i mentioned above, the tables are dynamic. if the number of amount gets bigger the amount adds a new row and the amount(abs) always keeps the two empty cells between. Any suggestions help is apperciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `RemoveDuplicates()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub Test()
    With Worksheets("MySheetName") ' change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            With .Range(.Find(What:="Amount(ABS)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1), .Cells(.Count))
                .Offset(, 1).Value = .Value
                .Offset(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it just copy and paste, it doesn't remove the duplicated.

Comment: it acts as per your requirements on a data set as shown in your question: have you tried it like that?

Comment: Yes i have tried it, it simply copy the whole range and paste it instead of removing the duplicates

Comment: Well, starting from the data layout as you gave in your question and running my code I got both copy/pasting and deletion of duplicates. So, either your actual data layout isn't as the one you showed or you're not running my code

Comment: I have updated the the dataset i have, the idea is copy from column j to Q. i have changed the offset(,7) but did not work.

Comment: Well, first off you should not change the question. "Chamaleon" questions are not allowed. You post a question, you get answers for that question and you provide adequate feedback for given answers. So, if my answer solved your _original_ question, then plese mark it as accepted and possibly up-vote it. On the other hand if you were the one to down vote it only because it didn't work in a data set different  from the ne given in the _original_ question, then please remove the down vote too.

Comment: Of course you may have new different needs and issues, but then first you give appropriate feedback to the first question and then you post a new one with the new issues

Answer (score 0):

### If you have access to the `UNIQUE` function in excel:

1. Determine your range of ABS Amounts using the defined variables `Found` and `lr`
2. Output the `UNIQUE` function to the right to de-dup your range
3. Clear the formula/spill range with a value transfer (`Range.Value = Range.Value`)

---

```
Sub Social_Distance()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- Update Sheet Name
Dim Found As Range, lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Found = ws.Range("A1:A" & lr).Find(What:="Amount(ABS)", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then

    Found.Offset(, 1) = "Unique Values"
    Found.Offset(1, 1) = "=UNIQUE(" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Offset(1).Row, 1), ws.Cells(lr, 1)).Address(False, False) & ")"

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Offset(1).Row, 2), ws.Cells(lr, 2)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Offset(1).Row, 2), ws.Cells(lr, 2)).Value

End If

End Sub
```